# How can I get Teams Messages in text from Microsoft Graph API using Data Factory

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-data-factory, html-to-text

In another context (Email) I've used a Header like "Prefer: outlook.body-content-type=text" so was wondering / hoping you could do similar for Teams Messages, but have not been able to find out ... an alternative is to convert the HTML to text afterwards, but I can't find a good way to do that either, in ADF

Answer (score 0):

A bit more digging turned up an SQL function i.e. works in SQL but not elsewhere, so is not a completely general solution, but is still far better than the plethora of other partially working ideas out there: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/16/sql-server-udf-user-defined-function-to-strip-html-parse-html-no-regular-expression/?msclkid=86efadffbbeb11ec84e6dde4b1c0b6fe